# Recursive calls

Tags: recursion, stack

Below code performs recursive calls.

```
int fib(int n){
   if(n==0) 
     return 0;

   return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

Will this recursive calls perform **fib(n-2)** call only after finishing till the last call of **fib(n-1)**? or both **fib(n-1)** and **fib(n-2)** occur concurrently for each of the current call?

Comment: That would depend upon the language you use.  It looks like Java, and IIRC, Java would complete the first expression before calculating the second one.  Some functional languages have at least a bit of concurrency in calculating sub-expressions.  But this algorithm will be quite slow for larger values unless you add some memoization.  And actually it's wrong, since `fib(1)` would require `fib(-1)` which would subsequently call with every negative integer.  You need to handle the `n = 1` case.

Comment: Why don't you single-step it in the debugger and find out for yourself? Or add some output statements? Probably give you a better answer than asking, and you'll better understand the answer.